# 'DataHandler' already contains a definition for 'instance'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please help me to solve this problem on my unity, I have tried but no result.

[image: my DataHandler class]

[image: the error message]

Comment: Please add code and data as text [(using code formatting)](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#duplicate=0), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and other reasons explained in detail here. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named 2 variables "instance". Rename one.

**edit**:
your code shows:

```
private static DataHandler instance;
public static DataHandler instance;
```

my suggestion would be to either remove one of them (cause I don't think this makes any sense) or to rename one:

```
private static DataHandler _instance;
public static DataHandler instance;
```

Comment: which one, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify